# A system of polynomial equations resides in a vector space. Which vector space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've heard that, when solving a system of multivariate polynomial equations, the system is considered to be made up of vectors from some vector space.  Which vector space?  How is it formed, and what benefits are there for considering it as a vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add two such equations, you get another such equation. If you multiply such an equation by a scalar, again you get another such equation. You have the "zero equation", $0 = 0,$ scalar distributive laws, etc. Thus, the set of such equations satisfies the axioms for a vector space.

Thus, the set of such equation *is* the vector space in question, and the "vectors" are the individual equations.

As far as benefits, it allows you to talk about linear independence, spanning sets, basis, etc.

Comment: So, for example, it would allow for a change of basis (the Grobner basis, for example)?  You answered quite well what the space is, but I'm still not clear on why the individual things matter.  For instance, if two equations are linearly dependent...so what?

Comment: Groebner bases relate to ideals, so the relevant the multipliers are not necessarily scalars.

Comment: I suppose a better question would be something like this:  If I have a system of polynomial equations, are there any techniques that make it easier to solve them (or better understand their solutions) that rely on the vector space they make up?

Comment: If the equations are _linear_ equations with coefficients in a field, then the vector space idea is potentially useful. For nonlinear equations, it's useful only as a preliminary step -- you can drop from the system, one equation at a time, any equations which are linearly dependent on the (remaining) others.